# Simple 2 way Binding silverlight datagrid to a list<T> Question

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a silverlight app using RIA DataDomainService.

Silverlight app has one page with DataGrid.

I've set the ItemSource property of the DataGrid to the list in the Loaded event e.g.

```
//gets the list
List<Data> data = GetTheList();//returns the list of data
dataGrid.ItemSource = data;
```

This works the first time. The second time, I use the same above lines but I insert a new Data object in the list and then bind the list to the dataGrid using 
**dataGrid.ItemSource = data but it does not update the grid.**
Grid remains the same.

On the xaml side, in the DataGrid tag:

```
ItemSouce = {Binding data, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Is this binding correct?  Why does it bind the first time and not the second time with the new list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, setting the ItemSource in both XAML and code is redundant -- the code behind will overwrite your XAML Binding setting.

Try using an ObservableCollection instead of a List - it automatically notifies the View when items are added or removed. Then you shouldn't have to set data.ItemSource more than once.

```
ObservableCollection<Data> data = GetTheList();
dataGrid.ItemSource = data;
```

When you add or remove items from the ObservableCollection, the grid should automatically change. You'll have to make sure GetTheList() returns an ObservableCollection, and use that to store your 'Data' objects.

*** edit - if using ObservableCollection doesn't fit well with existing code, try setting ItemsSource to null before updating it. ex:

```
private void updateMyDataGrid()
{
    List<Data> data = GetTheList();
    dataGrid.ItemSource = null;
    dataGrid.ItemSource = data;
}
```

Comment: I added ObservableCollection<Data> data = new ObservableCollection(GetTheList());  and changed XAML ItemSource={Binding} but no luck at all.  I also tried {Binding data, Mode=TwoWay}.  What should be done?

Comment: What's inside the GetTheList() method? Does this still return a List<>? If you get rid of the List<> entirely and just use an ObservableCollection<> to store the items, and then add/remove items there, it should update the data grid automatically.

Comment: Also see my edit -- setting the ItemSource to null before changing it might be the easiest fix for your situation.

Comment: I noticed another issue.  I have a RIA service. It has a static List<Data> object. Initially I create it with Data[0].Id = 0.  DataGrid picks it up. I then update its first item and send over.  I noticed the item was being updated in the RIA service i.e. Data[0].Id = 1 but on the silverlight page side, it receives the collection but the collection is not any more modified. Data[0].Id is 0 instead of 1. What I need to send a modified collection? May be that's an issue?

Comment: Could you post the code from the RIA service and the GetTheList() method?

Comment: Please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508113/ria-service-class-objects-are-not-updated  I posted this question because that's the actual problem. The list object that I am getting from RIA service is always OLD and not the modified one.

Answer (score 0):

First , you dont need to do a "rebind" and set the itemsource again , meaning when a new data object is added to the list , the data grid will get updated automatically.

This link should help : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGrid_Silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `ObservableCollection` and the class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
ObservableCollection<Data> data = GetTheList();
dataGrid.ItemSource = data;
```

Something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Data>data;
    public ObservableCollection<Data>Data{
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            data=value;
            // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the property is updated
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }


// Declare the PropertyChanged event
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

// NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
// source property that is being updated.
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: In my .xaml.cs page, I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged but if (PropertyChanged != null) is always null. Also I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface on Data class and added NotifyPropertyChanged("<PROPERTY NAME>") but still no luck.
 Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste your data setter and getter methods?